# RuntimeError: numel: integer multiplication overflow

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensor, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to build a generative recurrent GAN architecture for a multi-variate time-series data. Here is the discriminator of my model:

```
from torchgan.models import Generator, Discriminator
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class RGANDiscriminator(Discriminator):
    def __init__(self,
                 sequence_length,
                 input_size,
                 hidden_size=None,
                 num_layers=1,
                 dropout=0,
                 last_layer=None,
                 device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"),
                 **kwargs):
        
        hidden_size = hidden_size or input_size
        self.device = device
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.label_type ="none"
        # Set kwargs (might overried above attributes)
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

        super(RGANDiscriminator, self).__init__(self.input_size,
                                                self.label_type)
        # Build RNN layer    
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_size,
                           hidden_size=hidden_size,
                           num_layers=num_layers,
                           batch_first=True)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)
        self.last_layer = last_layer    
        # Initialize all weights.
        self.rnn.apply(init_weights)
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.linear.weight)

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.randn((self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)).to(self.device)
        c0 = torch.randn((self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)).to(self.device)
        print(f"input {x.shape}")
        print(f"x: {x}")
        length =  torch.LongTensor([torch.max((x[i,:,0]!=0).nonzero()).item()+1 for i in range(x.shape[0])])
        packed = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(
            x, length, batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False
        )
        out_packed, (_, _) = self.rnn(packed, (h0, c0))
        y, _ = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(out_packed, batch_first=True)
        y = self.dropout(y)
        y = self.linear(y)
        return y if self.last_layer is None else self.last_layer(y)
```

This is the training module of my model:

```
def train(self, epochs, writer_frequency=1, saver_frequency=20):
    avg_mmd = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        mmd = []
        for batch_idx, (data_attribute, data_feature) in enumerate(self.real_train_dl):
            data_attribute = data_attribute.to(self.device)
            input_feature = data_feature.to(self.device)
            batch_size = data_attribute.shape[0]
            ### Train Discriminator: max log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
            noise = gen_noise((batch_size, self.sequence_length[0], self.noise_dim)).to(self.device)
            print(f"Noise:{noise.shape}")
            print(f"data attribute {data_attribute.shape}")
            noise = torch.cat((data_attribute, noise), dim=2)
            print(f"noise again : {noise.shape}")
            input_feature = torch.cat((data_attribute, input_feature), dim=2)
            print(f"input_feature : {input_feature.shape}")
            fake = self.generator(noise)
            print(f"fake :{fake.shape}")
            x = fake.clone()
            x = x.permute(0,2,1)
            padded = nn.ConstantPad1d((0, input_feature.shape[1] - fake.shape[1]), 0)(x)
            x = padded.permute(0,2,1)
            print(f"new fake :{x.shape}")
            mmd.append(calculate_mmd_rbf(torch.mean(fake, dim=0).detach().cpu().numpy(),
                                         torch.mean(data_feature, dim=0).detach().cpu().numpy()))
            fake = torch.cat((data_attribute, x), dim=2)
            disc_real = self.discriminator(input_feature).view(-1)
            lossD_real = self.criterion(disc_real, torch.ones_like(disc_real))
            disc_fake = self.discriminator(fake).view(-1)
            lossD_fake = self.criterion(disc_fake, torch.zeros_like(disc_fake))
            lossD = (lossD_real + lossD_fake) / 2
            self.discriminator.zero_grad()
            lossD.backward(retain_graph=True)
            self.optimizer_dis.step()

            ### Train Generator: min log(1 - D(G(z))) <-> max log(D(G(z))
            output = self.discriminator(fake).view(-1)
            lossG = self.criterion(output, torch.ones_like(output))
            self.generator.zero_grad()
            lossG.backward()
            self.optimizer_gen.step()
```

This the error message

```
INFO:config_logger:Batch Size: 40
INFO:config_logger:Noise Dimension: 5
INFO:config_logger:d_rounds: 1
INFO:config_logger:g_rounds: 1
INFO:config_logger:Device: cuda:0
INFO:config_logger:Input Dimension: 14
INFO:config_logger:Output Dimension: 12
INFO:config_logger:Sequence Length: (382,)
Noise:torch.Size([40, 382, 5])
data attribute torch.Size([40, 382, 14])
noise again : torch.Size([40, 382, 19])
input_feature : torch.Size([40, 382, 26])
fake :torch.Size([40, 340, 12])
new fake :torch.Size([40, 382, 12])
input torch.Size([40, 382, 26])
input torch.Size([40, 382, 26])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5cea213d3975> in <module>
    676                          time_logging_file=time_logging_file, batch_size=batch_size,
    677                          config_logging_file=config_logging_file)
--> 678     trainer.train(epochs=epoch, writer_frequency=1, saver_frequency=save_frequency)

8 frames
<ipython-input-2-5cea213d3975> in train(self, epochs, writer_frequency, saver_frequency)
    592                 disc_real = self.discriminator(input_feature).view(-1)
    593                 lossD_real = self.criterion(disc_real, torch.ones_like(disc_real))
--> 594                 disc_fake = self.discriminator(fake).view(-1)
    595                 lossD_fake = self.criterion(disc_fake, torch.zeros_like(disc_fake))
    596                 lossD = (lossD_real + lossD_fake) / 2

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-2-5cea213d3975> in forward(self, x)
    370         c0 = torch.randn((self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)).to(self.device)
    371         print(f"input {x.shape}")
--> 372         print(f"x: {x}")
    373         length =  torch.LongTensor([torch.max((x[i,:,0]!=0).nonzero()).item()+1 for i in range(x.shape[0])])
    374         packed = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py in __format__(self, format_spec)
    857         if self.dim() == 0 and not self.is_meta and type(self) is Tensor:
    858             return self.item().__format__(format_spec)
--> 859         return object.__format__(self, format_spec)
    860 
    861     @_handle_torch_function_and_wrap_type_error_to_not_implemented

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py in __repr__(self, tensor_contents)
    425             )
    426         # All strings are unicode in Python 3.
--> 427         return torch._tensor_str._str(self, tensor_contents=tensor_contents)
    428 
    429     def backward(

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/_tensor_str.py in _str(self, tensor_contents)
    635     with torch.no_grad():
    636         guard = torch._C._DisableFuncTorch()
--> 637         return _str_intern(self, tensor_contents=tensor_contents)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/_tensor_str.py in _str_intern(inp, tensor_contents)
    566                         tensor_str = _tensor_str(self.to_dense(), indent)
    567                     else:
--> 568                         tensor_str = _tensor_str(self, indent)
    569 
    570     if self.layout != torch.strided:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/_tensor_str.py in _tensor_str(self, indent)
    326         )
    327     else:
--> 328         formatter = _Formatter(get_summarized_data(self) if summarize else self)
    329         return _tensor_str_with_formatter(self, indent, summarize, formatter)
    330 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/_tensor_str.py in __init__(self, tensor)
    113 
    114         else:
--> 115             nonzero_finite_vals = torch.masked_select(
    116                 tensor_view, torch.isfinite(tensor_view) & tensor_view.ne(0)
    117             )

RuntimeError: numel: integer multiplication overflow
```

I will appreciate if anyone coould help me to understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow means that your operations are exploding in value, so much that the results occupy too much memory and the program cannot keep running. This means you experience numerical instability. Usually it is caused by exploding gradients, and there are mathematical tips to stop over/underflows from happening:

- Identities: for example [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O94pi.png) problem shows how you can apply mathematical identities so that the computed values are more numerically stable
- Data normalization: make sure that the data is normalized, so that the layers of your network don't explode when multiplying the matrices. Also try monitoring the values of your weights closely to identify parts of t he Architecture that may be causing these overflows.
- Lower the learning rate: at higher learning rates, overflows may also be experienced due to positive feedback loops

[here](https://medium.com/data-arena/overflow-and-underflow-in-deep-learning-22e5df529b2f) is an article that explains more in depth

Answer (score -1):

It might be that the class labels might be greater than the number of classes present in the dataset. Eg. you have CIFAR10 dataset with 10 classes, but somewhere in the dataset you have a class label